# Changing angle to snap during rotation

Tags: transforms, snapping

When I rotate an object with CTRL pressed, it rotates with 5 degree step. Can I change it so that it skips 15 degrees instead?

Comment: it looks like it's not possible if we judge by this discussion here (2019): https://blenderartists.org/t/rotate-by-increments/639809/10 ... but someone suggests that you can rotate 5 degrees then press shift R to repeat

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't manage to find that thread. Maybe it would make a future feature request.